# "one/two/three-car households" vs "single/dual/triple-car households" (attributive forms)

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, numbers, expression-choice, attributive-nouns

Which way is more natural when it comes to numbers of things that people have or own? For example, the numbers of cars owned by households:

> The rate of single/dual/triple-car households is increasing.
>
> The rate of one/two/three-car households is increasing.

I feel like cardinal numbers are only suitable when you talk about parts of a system or machine:

> a two-wheel vehicle
>
> a one-way ticket/street
>
> a three-way tie between A City, B City and C City
>
> a five-year plan presented to the cabinet

When it comes to people with agency, ownership or possession, I feel like the adjectives *single*,  *dual*, *triple*, etc. are more appropriate

> a dual-citizenship individual
>
> a single-income family

But then there are also cases where no humans are involved like:

> a single/dual-core CPU

So how do you determine which cases to use numbers and which to use adjectives in attributive forms?

Comment: Google Ngrams suggests [one-car family is much more common than single-car family](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one-car+family%2Csingle-car+family&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), and doesn't like double-car at all. I don't think there's a general rule; use what other people say if you're responding to their research or they ask you to work, and realise it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: Double-decker, triple treat, quad-rotor drone. Your sense of how this works is wrong. When the number is a free option, go with the number. It is usually highly restricted when attributives are trotted out.

Comment: @StuartF Your search seems to be faulty. Look at the error messages "
Replaced one-car family with [one - car family] to match how we processed the books.
info
Replaced single-car family with [single - car family] to match how we processed the books." Normally there should be actual results, but here there are no citations that perfectly match the spelling "one-car" or "single-car" (without spaces)

Comment: @StuartF I skip the word "family" and got [completely different graphs](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one-car%2Csingle-car&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), again with no citations whatsoever. I don't think Ngrams Viewer is the best tool for this kind of search.

Comment: @StuartF If Google Books treats "one-car" as two separate words, not a compound, then it's no wonder there are more results for "one car". There's simply no way "single" could be more common than "one".

Comment: I sincerely doubt that there is any consistent rule here.